# Trailing spaces do not change color qtextedit

Tags: python, pyside2

Having a QTextEdit, I want to insert a string with a background color. But when doing so, the spaces at the end do not change color. Although I was able to create a mcve, it turns out that rewriting the code makes the problem go away.

Next, the mcve:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Terminal(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, handler, width=80, height=30):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet("Terminal {background-color: black;"
                                     "color: white;"
                                     "font: 10pt Consolas}")
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)

        self.setPlainText("\n".join([" " * width] * height))
        
        self._width = width
        self._cursor = self.textCursor()

        self._handler = handler(self)
        next(self._handler)

    def say(self, row, col, text, **kwargs):
        format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            getattr(format, f"set{key}")(value)

        start = row * (self._width + 1) + col

        self._cursor.setPosition(start)
        self._cursor.setPosition(start + len(text), QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)

        self._cursor.insertText(text, format)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

@Terminal
def widget(win):
    win.say(0, 0, "hello  ", Background=QtGui.QColor("red"))
    yield

widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

What could I have done wrong?

**Edit:** When the window is maximized, the spaces are colored. I will see the cause of this.

Comment: For future reference, please avoid code that doesn't really affect the problem (see [mre]): the class decorator is completely irrelevant to the issue, and its code portion is just misleading as it is distracting.

Comment: Sorry, you're right that there is extra code, but I tried to do a mcve and I know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! It turns out that QTextEdit automatically added line breaks so that the text enters the widget.

Therefore, I just had to pass:

```
self.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.NoWrap)
```

Comment: The *actual* problem comes from the fact that text background is only shown within the boundaries of *actually displayed text*, which is not the case for blank spaces at the end of a *wrapped* line. Note that the issue is also partially related to the fact that you mistakenly used `setStyleSheet()` (which primarily affects the widget) while the proper usage is to use the QTextEdit [`document()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#document-prop) and then call [`setDefaultStyleSheet()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#defaultStyleSheet-prop) with correct syntax and proper tags for `setHtml()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and advice!